# How to use constants in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

I would like to use constants in PHP but `"WEB"` gets interpreted as `false`. I never used constants before, what do I miss?

```
define("WEB", true);
define("MOBILE", false);
define("DESKTOP", false);


if (defined('MOBILE' == true) || defined('DESKTOP' == true) ){
echo "MOBILE or DESKTOP";
} else if (defined('WEB' == true)) {
echo "WEB";
}
```

Comment: That's not how you use `defined`.  You don't put the `== true` *inside* the function call.  `defined('MOBILE') == true`, or just drop the `== true` altogether: `if(defined('WEB')){`.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `defined()` incorrectly. You are not checking if the constants are defined. You are checking their values. Just check them like you would a variable:

```
if (MOBILE == true || DESKTOP == true ){
echo "MOBILE or DESKTOP";
} else if (WEB == true) {
echo "WEB";
}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
if (MOBILE || DESKTOP){
echo "MOBILE or DESKTOP";
} else if (WEB) {
echo "WEB";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`defined` gives you whether or not the constant exists, not its value.

```
if (MOBILE || DESKTOP){
  echo "MOBILE or DESKTOP";
} else if (WEB) {
  echo "WEB";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if constant is defined, your code should be:

```
define("WEB", true);
define("MOBILE", false);
define("DESKTOP", false);

if(defined('MOBILE') || defined('DESKTOP'))
  echo "either MOBILE or DESKTOP is defined";
elseif(defined('WEB')) echo "WEB is defined";
```

If you want to check if constant value is true or false it would be

```
if(MOBILE || DESKTOP)
  echo "either MOBILE or DESKTOP is true";
elseif(WEB) echo "WEB is true";
```